# How to get different destination files with out overwriting in a folder using Flat file destination in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

Requirement : There are 2 excel files in a Folder A which needs to be loaded  in the database table separately ( using For Each loop container and database table is truncated each time the data is loaded)and after doing some calculations export  the data to the Folder B using flatfile destination.

Issue:when the first file was processed successfully  In the Folder B there will be a destination file.

For Example:

TestFile_+  RIGHT( 0  + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART( mm ,GetDate()) ,2) +RIGHT( 0  + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART( dd ,GetDate()),2) + (DT_WSTR,4)DATEPART( yyyy ,GetDate())  +RIGHT( 0  + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART( hh ,GetDate()),2)+RIGHT( 0  + (DT_WSTR,2)DATEPART( mi ,GetDate()),2) + .txt

When the second file was processed, it will append the data to the existing file ( If we uncheck the "Overwrite data in the file" in the Flat file destination editor) or it will overwrite the data in the existing file (If we check the "Overwrite data in the file" in the Flat file destination editor)

My question is, How to get the 2 different  destination files in the Folder B.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Give the second file a different name from the first one, and you will get two different files.

Comment: In the above example Filename is hard coded i.e; TestFile_ . only datetime stamp will be different. Nice suggestion by you to give different file name . can you please let me know  how to give different filenames  each time the file is generated.

Comment: You can either use a variable (expression) for the file name, and change it for the second file, or you can use two different flat file connection managers, and give them both different names.